# Using switch in Java to assign additional values

Tags: java, switch-statement

Im new to java and trying to write a switch. Where depending on a value of guess different prize will be given. I'm doing something wrong because compiler says variable already defined. But how can I not define it, so that switch knows what value to look for to give what prize?

```
if (guess == randomNom)
{
    System.out.println(" You Win! ");
    player.setEarning(player.getEarn() + guess * 10);

    int reward = guess;
    String prize = "";

    switch(reward)
        {
    case 1: int reward = 10;
            String prize = " Prize #1";
    break;

    case 2: int reward = 20 ;
        String prize = "Prize #2";
    break;

    case 3: int reward = 30; 
        String prize = "Prize #3";
    break;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just remove `String` in front of all of the `String prize =` statements except the first (and same with `int` and `reward`). You only declare a variable **once**. Afterward, you just use it. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/java-tutorial.html refer to this, you might want to start at the beginning.

Comment: Also, you shourld be aware that all those `int reward...` inside your switch, declare a new variable only visible INSIDE that `case`.

Answer (score 2):

compiler say OK, You try to create 'another variable with the same name', whats wrong. Delete duplicated declarations

```
if (guess == randomNom)
{
    System.out.println(" You Win! ");
    player.setEarning(player.getEarn() + guess * 10);

    int reward = guess;
    String prize = "";

    switch(reward)
    {
     case 1: reward = 10;
        prize = " Prize #1";
        break;

     case 2: reward = 20 ;
       prize = "Prize #2";
       break;

    case 3: reward = 30; 
       prize = "Prize #3";
       break;

...     
     }
```

Comment: Hi Jacek, As the OP already told he is new to java, solving his problem with code will not help him. Instead explain the logic behind what he is doing wrong and what is the correct way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these lines

```
String prize = "";
String prize = " Prize #1";
String prize = "Prize #2";
```

When you Assign a variable in above manner i.e. `data type` followed by variable name compiler assumes that you want to define a new variable with some value.

Instead, you should define it once

```
String prize = ""; // Data type followed by variable name is to define new variable
```

and update subsequently

```
prize = " Prize #1"; //just the variable name with assignment operator to assign new value to existing variable.
prize = " Prize #2";
```

Comment: Proper explanation. :-)